# pandas groupby rank removes index, returns all 1s

Tags: python, pandas

My dataframe looks like this:

```
    name1  name2   value
 1  Jane   Foo     2
 2  Jane   Bar     4
 3  John   Foo     7
 4  John   Bar     1
```

If I do `df.groupby(['name1', 'name2']).count()` I get:

```
              value
name1  name2
Jane   Foo    1
Jane   Bar    1
John   Foo    1
John   Bar    1
```

But I'm trying to find the rank of each value within each multiindex group. Ideally, if I use `df.groupby(['name1', 'name2']).rank()` I should get:

```
             value
name1  name2
Jane   Foo    2
Jane   Bar    1
John   Foo    1
John   Bar    2
```

But instead I simply get:

```
    value
  1  1
  2  1
  3  1
  4  1
```

with the names of the grouped columns removed, only the index numbers as the index, and the rank value for all rows equaling 1. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need working with numeric - so it seems need grouping be first column `name1` and return `rank` for `value`:

```
df['rank'] = df.groupby('name1')['value'].rank(method='dense', ascending=False).astype(int)
print (df)
  name1 name2  value  rank
1  Jane   Foo      2     2
2  Jane   Bar      4     1
3  John   Foo      7     1
4  John   Bar      1     2
```